# Quick General Question regarding Interior Point Methods

Tags: optimization, algorithms, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, non-convex-optimization

[image]So I noticed that equality constraints cannot be treated with interior barriers, which means we can only work with inequality constraints. I know that a trick sometimes used is to double the amount of inequality constraints by keeping $g_i(x) \le 0$ and generating new $-g_i^{new} \ge 0$. However I am guessing this will not work with interior barrier algorithms right?

This makes me wonder whether this also applies to the "basic interior point method?" for which i have included a photo of the algorithm (not sure if there is a more specific name for this provided algorithm)?

So to be more specific with my question, can i also use this algorithm using only equality constraints? If i can, does this mean we remove the 2nd column and 2nd row from the matrix in step b), as well as the 2nd entry in the left and right hand vector? Or do we simply set all inequalities $g_i(x) \le 0$ as being nothing (zero) and move along as if nothing were different?

I am trying to get this to work with my optimization problem
$$
\min_{\theta \in \mathbb{C}^{n} } Tr((\textbf{HH}^H)^{-1}) \; \; s.t. \; \; Re^2(\theta_i)+Im^2(\theta_i) -1 =0 \; \; \forall i \in \{1,\ldots,64\}
$$
Where $\textbf{H}$ is a linear function of $\theta$, and $n=64$

Super appreciate any help, I am a total noob to this stuff.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Equality constraints are naturally supported by IPM. They simply appear "as is" in the KKT conditions and linearized in the linear system (augmented or KKT system) resulting from the Newton step.

This is actually true for all Newton-based methods (IPM, SQP, etc). The difference is how they handle *inequality* constraints. Modern IPM add slacks (which results in equality constraints only), then use a barrier term for the bounds (original variables + slacks). In modern formulations, all the iterates are *interior* wrt the primal bounds (original variables + slacks) and the dual bounds, not wrt the original constraints.

Edit: I'm guessing that $h$ in your screenshot are equality constraints.

Comment: Thank you for your response! So i am guessing I was wrong in saying that interior barrier methods cannot use equality constraints? Since my reading material has a separate pseudoalgorithm ($\textit{not the photo of alg 4.26})$ for the interior barrier method using only $g_i (x) \le 0$ I must double the amount of inequality constraints by adding new $-g_i ^{new}(x) \ge 0$ for the interior barrier method to work with my opt. problem?

Comment: And what do you think about the algorithm 4.26 I added a photo of? Is the "deletion" of rows and columns I talked about in my question reccomended for my opt. problem? or rather should I simply set all $g_i (x) \le 0$ to be nothing (zero) in the big matrix in step b)? The dimensions and how to set up this matrix is holding me back.

Comment: You shouldn't duplicate the constraints. On your screenshot, $g$ are inequality constraints (that's why you have an identity block in the linear system: the jacobian wrt the slacks $y$) and $h$ are equality constraints. So simply use Alg 4.26 because it works totally fine whether you have inequalities, equalities or both. Edit: yes, if you don't have inequalities, delete the parts (rows and columns) corresponding to $g$ and $y$.

Comment: Excellent thank you! and sorry I think I made my question rather confusing. With respect to duplicating the inequality constraints, this was not regarding alg 4.26 (the screenshot). Rather I was referring to another interior point method, (interior barrier) and wondering whether i should take my equality constraints $h_i(x)=0$ and convert them into inequality constraints by generating twice as many constraints through doing $h_i(x) \le 0$ and $h_i(x) \ge 0$

Comment: The reason for this question is because my reading material says the interior barrier method is not used for equality constraints, but rather only used for inequality constraints. Thank you!

Comment: Well, use a standard IPM (Alg 4.26) ;)

Comment: wait I can't tell for sure whether you're implying they cannot. Can or cannot Interior barriers use equality constraints even with the trick I talked about in the last comment? Sorry, i'm kind of an idiot so i require explicit statements

Comment: All the interior-point methods work with equality constraints. If your book claims otherwise, show us the section.

Comment: I added the photo to the top of the post. Would love if you could clarify the confusion for me! Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: I think they consider only unconstrained optimization here: they move the inequalities into the barrier term (so $g(x) \le 0$ is transformed into $\ln(-g(x))$ and moved to the objective), which results in an unconstrained problem. However, Alg 4.26 is for constrained optimization and handles equalities and inequalities.